Sdk 34 - Foregroud Service onBoot with microphone - Authorization Error
I'm facing on an error, I successfully develop a Receiver that is started onBoot, but I need to start a foreground service with microphone authorizations and the error above appears, whereas the authorizations are granted when I started the foreground service in the MainActivity as usual:

java.lang.SecurityException: Starting FGS with type microphone callerApp=ProcessRecord{dc0ba1f 16443:com.example.service/u0a625} targetSDK=34 requires permissions: all of the permissions allOf=true [android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MICROPHONE] any of the permissions allOf=false [android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_HOTWORD, android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT, android.permission.CAPTURE_MEDIA_OUTPUT, android.permission.CAPTURE_TUNER_AUDIO_INPUT, android.permission.CAPTURE_VOICE_COMMUNICATION_OUTPUT, android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO]  and the app must be in the eligible state/exemptions to access the foreground only permission

Manifest :
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo1"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/logo1"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Service"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">

    <service
        android:name=".MyForegroundService"
        android:foregroundServiceType="microphone"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"/>

    <receiver
        android:name=".NotificationReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

MyForegroundService.java
public class MyForegroundService extends Service {

private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_id";
private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Log.d("MyForegroundService", "onCreate");

    // Créer un canal de notification si nécessaire
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
            CHANNEL_ID,
            "My Foreground Service Channel",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
    );
    NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
    manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Log.d("MyForegroundService", "onStartCommand");

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("App en cours")
            .setContentText("Enregistrement audio en cours")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_assistant_photo_24)  // Assurez-vous que l'icône est valide
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .build();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            Log.d("MyForegroundService", "startForeground");
            startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification, ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MICROPHONE);
        }
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}

NotificationReceiver.java
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.d("Service", "NotificationReceiver onReceive");

    switch (Objects.requireNonNull(intent.getAction())) {
        case Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED:
            Log.d("MainActivity", "ACTION_DATE_CHANGED");
            break;
        case Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED:
            Log.d("MainActivity", "ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED");
            break;
        default:

            Log.d("MainActivity", "default : " + intent.getAction());
            break;
    }

    Log.d("MainActivity", "RECORD_AUDIO: " + ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, RECORD_AUDIO));
    Log.d("MainActivity", "PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED : " + PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);



    if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyForegroundService.class);
        context.startForegroundService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
}

As I said,  the autorisation "RECORD_AUDIO" is Granted.
Thanks a lot.
